# cartodb unable to upload datasets

Tags: cartodb

I run cartodb on my docker installation:
https://github.com/sabala12/docker-cartodb

The container is running on ubuntu:12.04.

When I try to upload a shape file it fails, and bundle exec script/resque
prints the following error:

```
2016-10-11 06:14:51 UTC: ogr2ogr exit code:       32512
2016-10-11 06:14:51 UTC: Ogr2ogr FAILED!
2016-10-11 06:14:51 UTC: ogr2ogr.exit_code = 32512
2016-10-11 06:14:51 UTC: ogr2ogr.command = OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO PG_USE_COPY=YES PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF-8   -f PostgreSQL  PG:"host=localhost p
ort=5432 user=development_cartodb_user_36d7afb4-b874-496a-9731-74cc25a42557 dbname=cartodb_dev_user_36d7afb4-b874-496a-9731-74cc25a42557_db passwo
rd=de3c434284b2c35533bfa59029c91a3f2246a815development_cartodb_user_36d7afb4-b874-496a-9731-74cc25a42557" -t_srs EPSG:4326  -lco DIM=2 -lco PRECIS
ION=NO /tmp/imports/20161011-11003-4epo3c/afg.geo.json  -nln cdb_importer.importer_04b55fae8f7a11e6b365408d5c55bdcb -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI  -doo PR
ELUDE_STATEMENTS="SET statement_timeout TO '1h'" -doo CLOSING_STATEMENTS='SET statement_timeout TO DEFAULT' -update 
2016-10-11 06:14:51 UTC: ogr2ogr.command_output = sh: 1: -f: not found
```

It seems ogr2ogr is missing, although it is installed and available in $PATH.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The package gdal2.1-static-bin was missing.